# Create json in python for Openrefine

Tags: python, json, openrefine

I'm scraping resources in python and I want to make a json file, using it in Openrefine to clean data.

Here's my code:

```
import json
import codecs

A = xpath
B = xpath
C = xpath
D = xpath

with codecs.open('info2.json', 'a', 'utf-8-sig') as f:
    json.dump({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D': D}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

It's all right until I'll upload the file in Openrefine: I can't click on the right node, but only on a specific element. Here's an example:

[image: I can click only on a specific element]

I think there's an error producing the json with python, I tryed putting two {{}} but it gives me a "dict" error, so I tryed putting elements into arrays but nothing worked.

As request, here is a part of the json:

[image]

p.s. I'm using codecs because there are non-latin characters

Comment: Can you paste the json in the question. It will help to reproduce the error in Refine.

Comment: Edited with a part of the json, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the node selectable in the OpenRefine import you need to enclose the array in a node - e.g.

```
{
  "DISTRIBUTION": [
    "JHU",
    "123"
  ],
  "IMMAGINE": {
    "IMMAGINELIST": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try as soon as possible!